# Zend include_once(myphpfile): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, zend-framework

this problem is driving me nuts. I know similar problems has already been submitted but no solution worked for me

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'Recruit/Model/DbTable/Volontari.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/html/fabio/recruit/application/../library:/var/www/html/fabio/recruit/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /usr/share/php/Zend/Loader.php

But actually file exists on server. This is part of my folder tree

```
source
  |__application
        |_ ....
  |__library
        |__Recruit
             |__Forms
             |   |__VolontariCreate.php
             |__Model
                 |__DBTable
                       |__Volontari.php
```

Form VolontariCreate.php works, so I don't think it can't find the path.

I also checked include paths with echo get_include_path(); 
and they're correct

If it can help, client is Ubuntu, server is Centos, zend version is 1.12.17dev

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Where is the 'Recruit' folder located? It's in the file string, but not in the tree.  Is recruit your application?  It looks like perhaps you need to add an additional '../' to your path.  Also possible case issue with the autoloader looking for a capital 'R' on the namespace/classloader

Comment: Yes, recruit is my application. Sorry, Recruit folder was missing in tree, I edited. Now tree is correct. In application.ini I declared namespace "Recruit_".

Comment: try dumping `__DIR__` to see where you are in your actual file tree.

Comment: OK. I will try this evening (I'm at work now)

Comment: Error was on path name different from class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that linux/unix file systems are case sensitive. On servers running Windows you can get away with whatever file case you fancy as they are case insensitive. As such your request to include:

```
Recruit/Model/DbTable/Volontari.php
```

Will fail because the actual path should be:

```
Recruit/Model/DBTable/Volontari.php
```

Notice the capital B in DB...

Comment: Yes that was the problem! Class name is Recruit_Model_DbTable_Volontari, while path was Recruit_Model_DBTable_Volontari. Thank you!